# How to write a logic expression with only NAND gates

Tags: logic

I want to convert a *logical expression* to have only **NAND** gates. I know that **NAND** is written as `¬(A⋀B)`.

I have the following *expression*: `(A⋁(¬B))⋀C`

How to write this expression only with **NAND**?

Answer (score 2):

```
Y = (A ⋁ (¬B)) ⋀ C
  = ¬¬{(A ⋁ (¬B)) ⋀ C}      //Double negation
  = ¬{¬(A V (¬B) V ¬C}      //De-Morgan law
  = ¬{(¬A ⋀ B) V ¬C}        //Reverse De-Morgan law
  = ¬{(¬A V ¬C) ⋀ (B V ¬C)} //Distributive law
  = ¬{¬(A ⋀ C) ⋀ ¬(¬B ⋀ C)} //Apply reverse De-Morgan law
```